# Shift+Enter button used for submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, html

i want to submit a form using shift+enter button instead of pressing a simply Enter Button.
Pl help me out

Comment: What if the user doesn't want too?

Comment: lol right...This would be a usability problem...

Comment: It's your job as a web developer to return this requirement to the client to explain to them that it will destroy usability. There is absolutely no good reason to ever implement this feature. Educate them.

Comment: What if the form is a text area where the user is typing a chat message, and submitting the form is how you send the message?

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to do this despite the usability problem that this poses...

```
$('#form').keydown(function(e) {
    if( e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey ) {  // When "Shift + Enter"
        $(this).trigger('submit'); 
    } else { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

Comment: actually client requirements is : when you click on submit button then form will submit and but when u click on enter button then form will not submit and another is use shift + enter for submit form also for that i used: <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="rightbtn" /> from this code enter will not used for submitting form and what should i do for shift + enter for submittinf same form also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13 && e.keyCode==16){  // 13=enter  16=shift
       //submit here
       alert('submit now');
    }
    else{
       e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Comment: Re: Usability, would have to agree.  Unless you have some notification explaining why and for good reason. Ours is not to judge.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.101/MobileCMS/js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    
    if(e.keyCode==13 && e.keyCode==16){ 
        alert("hello");// 13=enter  16=shift
    //submit here
    document.submitForm()
    }
    else{
      //nothing
    }

});

Comment: Added preventDefault(); Are you getting any js errors?  Also, are you tied to jquery 1.3.1 shown in code excerpt?

Comment: actually client requirements is :
when you click on submit button then form will submit and but when u click on enter button then form will not submit
and another is use shift + enter for submit form also
for that i used:
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="rightbtn" /> from this code enter will not used for submitting form and what should i do for shift + enter for submittinf same form also

Comment: give your image(button) an id like id="btnSubmit" loose the onclick and add check for button click along with the keydown event (use only the e.keyCode = 13 for the shift you want.

Comment: this is first one which i used before requirement
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Input" class="rightbtn" />
button is of green color

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use CTRL+ENTER to submit form。So that the user experience will be better。

```
<script language=javascript>
ie = (document.all)? true:false
if (ie){
function ctlent(eventobject){if(event.ctrlKey && window.event.keyCode==13){this.document.form1.submit();}}
}
</script>

<form action="http://www.TOMMYHU.CN" method=POST name=form1>
<textarea cols=95 name=Content rows=12 wrap=virtual onkeydown=ctlent()>
</textarea>
<input type=Submit value="Submit" name=Submit>
</form>
```

Comment: actually client requirements is : when you click on submit button then form will submit and but when u click on enter button then form will not submit and another is use shift + enter for submit form also for that i used: <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="rightbtn" /> from this code enter will not used for submitting form and what should i do for shift + enter for submittinf same form also

Answer (score 0):

Improving on zhaixiaohu's idea:

```html
<form action="." method="POST">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA");
  for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; ++i) {
    textareas[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
      if(ev.ctrlKey && ev.keyCode === 13){
        this.form.submit();
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

This…

- is pure Javascript
- attachs itself to all textareas, and submits the correct form
- works only in modern browsers, but might be extended to work with more browsers