# Submit a form using Shift + Enter

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shift+Enter button used for submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124141/shiftenter-button-used-for-submitting-form)

Actually client requirements is:

1. When you click on submit button then form will submit and but when you click on Enter button then form will not submit
2. Another is use Shift + Enter for submit form also for that I used: `input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="rightbtn"` from this code enter will not used for submitting form and what should I do for Shift + Enter for submitting same form also?

Comment: Possible duplicate? It's the same author posting an hour apart.

Comment: can you suggest some another code ...i tried but still it is not working

Comment: yes jordan...problem is that in previous i didnt mention requirement of client

Comment: @Jordan .. Ya i just see it !! :)

Comment: @Piyush, you should go edit your original question and delete this one. If you are unable to edit, add the client's requirements into a comment on the original question. Either way, this one needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiny jQuery-Script.

```
$("body").keyup(function(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey)
    {
        $("#form_id").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question in JavaScript
check if on loading the page if focus is on the submit button, 
if so then on clicking enter the page gets submitted,

so on page load set focus to some other element

```
document.getElementById('textField').focus();
```

for the second question use jQuery

```
$("form").keyup(function(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey)
    {
    $("#form_id").submit();
    }
});
```